# Ablatives of Agent in Ablative Absolutes in Early Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, ablative, ablative-absolute, early-latin, agent

It is (often) said that participles in Ablative Absolutes in Early Latin have an adjectival nature (e.g., see [Ruppel (2013: 124)](https://assets.cambridge.org/97805217/67620/frontmatter/9780521767620_frontmatter.pdf): "the Early Latin Ablative Absolute is not strongly verbal at all"). For some remarks on the verbal vs. adjectival passive distinction in Latin, please see this [previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/on-the-typical-ambiguity-of-porta-clausa-est).

If Ruppel's statement is correct, which I tend to think it is, one consequence that is not pursued by her is that the so-called ["ablative of agent"](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-agent)  could not appear in this non-finite participial construction in Early Latin. In contrast, in Classical Latin (e.g., see the following example from Caesar), Ablative Absolutes can appear with an ablative of agent:

> Commisso **ab equitibus** proelio, ... (Caes. *Civ.* 1.41).

So my empirical question is: **Are there any examples of "ablatives of agent" in Ablative Absolute constructions in Early Latin?**